# onClick fires the last items function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have an array of items which all have a function named `onClick()` this function can be executed from a `ng-repeat`

However what happens is that instead of executing the `onClick()` of the selected element, it call the function from the last element in the last. Why is this, and how can I prevent this?

My [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/michaeltotkorsgaard/789Ks/284/)

Comment: Please include the [MCVE], whether a snippet or code, in the question itself, don't simply link to an external resource.

Comment: onClick is an controller function define as $scope.onclick = function no need to loop it on links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because of closures in the for loop, the way to solve this in basic JavaScript would be an IIFE like in SeongHyeon Park's answer, but this is Angular so you should be using the native `forEach` loop rather then a `for` loop.

That way each iteration of the loop has its own self contained scope and you won't have any problems with closures.

So change your loop code to:

```
angular.forEach(links, function(link) {
    link.onClick = function(){
    console.info('click')
    $state.go(link.destination)
  }
  $scope.links.push(link)
})
```

[Full JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dibdab/789Ks/293/)

Answer (score 1):

```
// your code
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
    var link = links[i]
  link.onClick = function(){
    console.info('click')
    $state.go(link.destination)
  }
  $scope.links.push(link)
}
```

Problem is `hoisting`. `for` does not create block scope. It means `var`declation will be hoisted top on scope. simply, outside of for loop

```
var link;
var i;
for(i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    link = links[i];
    link.onClick = function() {
        $state.go(link.destination);
    };
    $scope.links.push(link);
}
```

can you firgure out?
link variable is last element in links array when for loop finished.

Therefore when you click `a` tag, $state go last destination always.

ok, here are fix version.

```
link.onClick = (function (link) {
     $state.go(link.destination);
}((link);
```

just change `onClick` function.

Answer (score 0):

I've modifyyour fiddler, take a look, and tell us if is that.
html:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
  {{ destination }}
  <a ng-click="onClick(link)" ng-repeat="link in links track by $index">{{link.text}}</a>
  <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

js:

```
    var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[ "ui.router", "AppCtrls"]);

myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider.state("state1", {
        url: "#",
        template: "<p>State 1</p>"
      }).state("state2", {
        url: "#",
        template: "<p>State 2</p>"
      });
});

var ctrls = angular.module("AppCtrls", []);

ctrls.controller( "Ctrl1", function($scope, $state) {
    $scope.links = [
        {
        text: 'state1',
        destination: 'state1'
      },
            {
        text: 'state2',
        destination: 'home'
      }
    ]
    $scope.destination = $state.current.name

    $scope.onClick = function(){
        console.info('click')
        $state.go(link.destination);
     };

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/789Ks/288/

Answer (score 0):

**Try something like that**

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ["ui.router", "AppCtrls"]);

myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state("state1", {
    url: "#",
    template: "<p>State 1</p>"
  }).state("state2", {
    url: "#",
    template: "<p>State 2</p>"
  });
});

var ctrls = angular.module("AppCtrls", []);

ctrls.controller("Ctrl1", function($scope, $state) {
  var links = [{
    text: 'state1',
    destination: 'state1'
  }, {
    text: 'state2',
    destination: 'state2' // changed from home to state2
  }]
  $scope.destination = $state.current.name
  $scope.links = []

  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var link = links[i]
    $scope.links.push(link)
  }
// outside the for loop
  $scope.onClick = function(link) {
    console.info('click')
    $state.go(link.destination)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl1">
  {{ destination }}
  <a ng-repeat="link in links" ng-click="onClick(link)">{{link.text}}</a>
  <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```